# Is there a name for the type of photography or layout where items are arranged on a grid?

Tags: photography, layout

Is there a name for this layout?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name for this type of layout is called [knolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoll_(verb)).

This term originated in 1987 though I believe the popularity of this sort of style blew up due to the [Things Organized Neatly](http://thingsorganizedneatly.tumblr.com/) blog.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't actually know the name until just a minute ago when I decided to do some in-depth research. So I learned something new as well!

Comment: Your googling is far superior to mine.

Comment: "The first person to knoll was Andrew Kromelow, a janitor at Frank Gehry's furniture store. At the time, Gehry was designing for a popular furniture brand called Knoll… …Kromelow would go through the store and find any tools that had been left out. He would then rearrange the tools on a flat surface so they were at right angles to one another. He called this knolling, because it reminded him of the angles in Florence Knoll's furniture pieces." — via [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/blog/what-is-knolling-the-overhead-photography-trend-explained)